# Getting Past Captcha - Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate a login process on a website using Selenium. I want to enter my data, then enter the captcha myself. However, when I click on the captcha I am given a large amount of captchas and errors. Is there any way for me to not run into constant captchas?

Answer (score 2):

Captchas are specifically designed to break automation. I would ask the Product Owner to add some kind of a cookie or mechanism to cause the chaptcha to not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as @Dominic said, CAPTCHA's can't be broken. But I've asked developers to include for test environment URL parameter which can be used in test environment to disable/hide CAPTCH-as. But If You like to investigate I've heard about this service http://deathbycaptcha.com that have to be paid of course.

Here is some complementary code:

```
import com.DeathByCaptcha.AccessDeniedException;
import com.DeathByCaptcha.Captcha;
import com.DeathByCaptcha.Client;
import com.DeathByCaptcha.SocketClient;
import com.DeathByCaptcha.HttpClient;

/* Put your DeathByCaptcha account username and password here.
   Use HttpClient for HTTP API. */
Client client = (Client)new SocketClient(username, password);
try {
    double balance = client.getBalance();

    /* Put your CAPTCHA file name, or file object, or arbitrary input stream,
       or an array of bytes, and optional solving timeout (in seconds) here: */
    Captcha captcha = client.decode(captchaFileName, timeout);
    if (null != captcha) {
        /* The CAPTCHA was solved; captcha.id property holds its numeric ID,
           and captcha.text holds its text. */
        System.out.println("CAPTCHA " + captcha.id + " solved: " + captcha.text);

        if (/* check if the CAPTCHA was incorrectly solved */) {
            client.report(captcha);
        }
    }
} catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
    /* Access to DBC API denied, check your credentials and/or balance */
}
```

This code wasn't tested, I've just found on web, maybe it will help You out.