# Selenium - Avoid getting CAPTCHAs

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape a login-only, bot-sensitive website.  After logging in, when I perform a simple selenium function like `driver.find_element_by_id('button').click()`, the website displays a message along the lines of **We think you are a bot.  Please complete the CAPTCHA below to continue.**

Is there any way for me to make selenium more human-like so I don't trigger CAPTCHAs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Past Captcha - Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516616/getting-past-captcha-selenium)

Comment: True dupe, but the dupe´d question has no accepted answer. May dupes are not useless at all? :\

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hopefully not.

You are scraping, i.e. you are developing a bot, and if you try to avoid being identified as a bot, it will just be a question of time until the captcha gets improved to detect your strategy.

Don´t do it. The captcha is there for a reason, which is: to detect and lockout bots!

Better check if the page you want to scrape supports an API that allows computer-to-computer communication. If there is one, use it. If there is none, suggest one, but depending on whether the web page owner wants to support your goals, or not, he might say "no".

Comment: Is this issue limited to selenium or does it apply to all web-access programs?  Are there any programs/libraries designed specifically to web scrape in a human-like manner without triggering CAPTCHAs?

Comment: No. Captchas fight all bots. They are there to prevent the usage of bots, and they are successfully in doing so because 1. there are lots of tasks a machine cannot easily perform, but a human can, and 2. while you might be able to make your bot more human-like, there will be patterns in its behavior that can be detected, and will be detected. And even if your bot would be advanced in mimicking a human user, a single captcha popping up randomly would effectively stop even that one.

Comment: Welp.  Looks like I'll have to keep downloading the data manually by hand.

Comment: I would even say you should re-think if your goal of downloading is legit at all. Obviously, we are talking about a site that the owner does not want to be cloned, for a reason.